# Transferring big files with cp command in terminal and see want to see process

Tags: macos, terminal, cp

I used the "cp" command to copy and paste a big directory (>300GB) to an external disk.

Now i want to see the process because it is running for almost 12 hours.

I pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> because someone else recommended it. And the output was:

> load: 3.10  cmd: cp 2343 uninterruptible 13.31u 1051.85s

What does this output mean?

Comment: In general, `rsync` is a better tool to use for big copies because it is restartable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [stty(1)](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stty.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/stty) page:

> The status line consists of the system load average, the 
>   current
>                    rent command name, its process ID, the event the process is waiting on (or the status of
>                    the process), the user and system times, percent cpu, and current memory usage.

Therefore;

System load average is 3.10

The current command running is "cp" with a Process ID of 2343, and it is uninterruptible.

I assume 13.31u means 13 hours of user time, and 1051.85s is the system time. There is no CPU percentage or RAM usage details however.

I'm not sure <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> is the solution you're looking for..